# Split classes into files which need to have access to class instances

Tags: python, class, oop

I have this example which shows two classes which have methods which need to be in contact to the other class instance. How can I split this classes into files?

```py
class A:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def do_something(self):
        print(b.name)

class B:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def do_something(self):
        print(a.name)


a = A("A")
b = B("B")

a.do_something()
```

Comment: *Why* do these classes need global access to each others' instance? This defeats the benefit of classes, since it means you can have only one instance each. What are your constraints that ``A`` and ``B`` have to satisfy?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi This example is extremely simple. I have a huge file with many classes which are PyQt5 windows and have to be connected.

Comment: Connected *how*? Is everything connected with everything? Will new windows appear and go? It seems like those windows connected with each should be explicitly told about each other, not assume every other window is global.

Comment: Sorry... I have oversimplified my problem. It is quite complex to explain. I have been able to fix it with Gabp's answer, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to split your code into the following modules:

**module_a.py**

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def do_something(self, b):
        print(b.name)
```

**module_b.py**

```
class B:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def do_something(self, a):
        print(a.name)
```

**main.py**

```
from module_a import A
from module_b import B

a = A("A")
b = B("B")
a.do_something(b) # output: B
```